# Bitmap is not being scaled correctly because of density

Tags: android, bitmap

I am loading a bitmap that is stored in the drawable-hdpi folder (with all the other images).

```
options.inScaled = false;

Bitmap rawBMP = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

Bitmap finalBMP = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(rawBMP, reqWidth, reqHeight, true);
```

the original bitmap is 512x512, thats also the size of rawBMP if i set inScaled to false.
The final bitmap only works on a device with less that 512 (my S2 with 480). On devices with higher res the final bmp size is reported as it should be, but the visible part of that image is the original size. So createScaledBitmap is creating a big bitmap but does not scale the original upwards.

If i set inScaled to true, i receive a rawBMP with LESS than original size but then the final bitmap seems to work but as you can imagine the quality suffers as it more than doubles in size.

On a Galaxy 10 tablet :

inScaled true : 512 original, 341 rawBMP, final 800 (density 160) final image is visible across the entire screen (height)

inScaled false: 510 original, 512 rawBMP, final 800 (density 240) final image visible part is still 512, the rest is filled with transparent, there was absolutely no scaling here.

I dont understand this behaviour. If i have a bmp with 512 pixels and want to scale it to 800 pixels and then just draw those pixels to the screen 1:1

**edit**

For arguments sake lets say i need the bitmap scaled this way, the code is a bit more than just this snippet

Comment: why the scaled bitmap at all? just use ImageView and appropriate  scaleType

Comment: First of all I would recommend you to not name a variable "final" as that will give you a compiler error. Furthermore, as @psink says, just use the ImageView to scale, or if you have a custom Canvas, use the matrix transform functionality.

Comment: lol, sorry that was just for this question, in code it has a different specific name that i didnt want to use here

Comment: I have a feeling you don't fully understand how Android deals with images and different screen densities. It'll be much easier to help you if you explain what you need - specifically.

Comment: i draw a LOT with canvas and i simply need the bitmap to be scaled to screensize(height on landscape) on every device